# Filtering Query with NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, not-exists

I am currently attempting to query a database using SQL Server in Visual Studio. The database in question contains payment information, primarily identifying transactions and their resulting software licenses via OrderID and License ID. Ocassionally, these licenses get revoked due to misuse.

Right now, I'm attempting to run a query that returns all customers based upon this:

```
Select 
   [Order].LastName,
   [Order].FirstName,
   [Order].CompanyOrganization,
   [Order].EmailAddress,
   [Order].Country,
   [License].LicenseID,
   [License].InstanceCount

From [Order], [License]

Where
    [License].OrderID = [Order].OrderID
    AND [Order].Status = 1
    AND not exists (Select LicenseID From [LicenseRevocation])

Order by [License].InstanceCount DESC;
```

The query returns no results, and I know it's because of the "NOT EXISTS" portion. However, I'm not sure why. Can somebody clear up how "EXISTS" works and how to implement it into my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a condition on which you check for values if there exist or not,

Also use `ON` clause syntax for your joins.

```
Select [Order].LastName
     , [Order].FirstName
     , [Order].CompanyOrganization
     , [Order].EmailAddress
     , [Order].Country
     , [License].LicenseID
     , [License].InstanceCount

From [Order] 
INNER JOIN [License] ON [License].OrderID = [Order].OrderID 

Where [Order].[Status] = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (Select 1 
                From [LicenseRevocation]
                WHERE LicenseID = [License].LicenseID)  --<-- you are missing this condition
Order by [License].InstanceCount DESC;
```

Comment: It works! Can you explain why I want to `Select 1` rather than a particular column? That's the only particular part I don't understand.

Comment: Logically there is no difference if it finds a row based on your condition defined in WHERE Clause it Selects 1 (True) else it returns NULL (False). When all you need is `true` or `false` I dont see the point of trying to return a column value, which may be more expensive then simply selecting 1.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `exists()` function is true if the query inside it would produce at least one record, thus `not exists()` is only true if the query inside it would produce zero records.

In your case you are querying the entire `LicenseRevocation` inside `not exists()`, so your query would only return anything if that table was completely empty.

You would use a condition in the query to look for a specific record in it, something like this:

```
not exists (Select * From [LicenseRevocation] Where LicenseID = [License].LicenceID)
```

That will make the query return the records where there is no corresponding record in the `LicenseRevocation` table.

Answer (score 0):

this solution uses `NOT IN` and proper `JOIN` syntax but should give you the result you want

```
SELECT  [Order].LastName, [Order].FirstName, [Order].CompanyOrganization, 
        [Order].EmailAddress, [Order].Country,
        [License].LicenseID, [License].InstanceCount
FROM    [Order] 
INNER JOIN [License] ON [License].OrderID = [Order].OrderID 
WHERE  [Order].Status = 1 
AND  [License].LicenseID NOT IN  (
     SELECT  LicenseID
     FROM    [LicenseRevocation] )
ORDER BY [License].InstanceCount DESC;
```

ps. use table `ALIAS`

Comment: Technically speaking the join syntax from the OP is proper. It is however the older ANSI-89 style join where yours is the newer ANSI-92 style join. The 92 style joins are easier to read and less prone to error.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks Sean, that's what I meant. More common and easier to read

Comment: And +1000 for suggesting using an alias. Might add to that to not use reserved words for object names because it is painful to work with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, write your query using proper JOINS, and use a standard LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
Select 
   [Order].LastName,
   [Order].FirstName,
   [Order].CompanyOrganization,
   [Order].EmailAddress,
   [Order].Country,
   [License].LicenseID,
   [License].InstanceCount

From [Order]
INNER JOIN [License] ON [License].OrderID = [Order].OrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LicenseRevocation] ON [License].LicenseID = [LicenseRevocation].LicenseID
Where [Order].Status = 1
AND [LicenseRevocation].LicenseID IS NULL

Order by [License].InstanceCount DESC;
```

Comment: Technically speaking the join syntax from the OP is proper. It is however the older ANSI-89 style join where yours is the newer ANSI-92 style join. The 92 style joins are easier to read and less prone to error. Also your query is not exactly the same. If there are more than 1 rows matching in LicenseRevocation you will get more rows returned.

Comment: I appreciate you comments on ANSI-89 vs ANSI-92. Regarding LEFT JOIN to LicenseRevocation, I agree except that we are filtering out any records that have a match, so the net result works correctly in this case. If we did not have the "WHERE [LicenseRevocation].LicenseID IS NULL" then I could completely agree with you.